# How do I parse this XSL file and read an element embed it in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, json, xml, html, xslt

I am currently trying to set up a primarily raw HTML5 web player for an IceCast station. I used to use ShoutCast and was able to pull data from an XML file. IceCast only provides its data via an XSL file and I am unsure of how I actually read that file to get the information I want.

The file in question [is here](http://reusable-box.me:8000/status-json.xsl) and contains this JSON content:

```
{ "icestats": 
  "admin":"calhoun347@gmail.com",
  "host":"gahgahshortme",
  "location":"The Cloud",
  "server_id":"Icecast 2.4.2",
  "server_start":"Thu, 09 Feb 2017 12:00:50 -0500",
  "server_start_iso8601":"2017-02-09T12:00:50-0500",
  "dummy":null}
}
```

I want to read the title element and display that on the webpage [Reusable-Box.me](http://reusable-box.me) where - at the current time - the text

> THIS IS A WORK IN PROGRESS TEXT

is displayed.

Additionally I would like the page on Reusable-Box.me to refresh itself every 10 seconds or so.

I think I know how to do the last part, I did it before with the XML files and the same method should work (I think). But I'm still lost on the first two parts.

I'm not saying I want someone to do this work for me, but I can't find any examples in any documentation for IceCast - for what I'm doing at all and it seems like something very basic.

Comment: The file from [Reusable-box.me](http://reusable-box.me:8000/status-json.xsl) is a JSON file and not an XSLT file. I have no idea why it has the wrong file extension.

Comment: That XSL file actually applies to XML from Icecast status and _produces_ result in JSON format that you can parse just like any other valid JSON.

Comment: @AlexParamonov I don't have or see any actual XML files though. I would love to have an XML file to pull from, thats the way I did things with shoutcast, but I don't see anywhere where icecasts produces this information in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation

http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/server-stats.html

Icecast uses XML internally so you can't easily get it with HTTP request.
But Icecast can convert its internal XML data representation to any format you like using XSL files that reside inside Icecat's "web" directory.
When you open Icecast status page in your browser that is

http://reusable-box.me:8000/

you see the HTML representation of internal XML data in HTML, that default behavior generated by `status.xsl` XSL file.

When you make a request to

http://reusable-box.me:8000/status-json.xsl

you get Icecast data in JSON format via `status-json.xsl` style sheet.

If you want XML you can place `status-xml.xsl` file with the follwoing contents:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

inside Icecast web directory and request it via

http://reusable-box.me:8000/status-xml.xsl

and you will get XML.

But you should better use JSON, because it is much easier to parse with Javascript, create a script (in jQuery, for example) that will pull http://reusable-box.me:8000/status-json.xsl every 10 seconds, as a result you will get a Javascript object created automatically from JSON that will contain all the data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising. My skills in web development are basically 0 and while I am interested in learning more and will probably try to play with using JSON and Javascript being able to get this data in XML means I can just refit my previous, existing work.

Comment: On second blush after putting that file in the icecast web directory I get an error when I do a GET request.